# PHP Array to string conversion error while posting JSON data

Tags: php, arrays

I am posting a json data into php using ajax. When I kept print_r($_POST), the result shows like below:

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
    )
)
```

I want to save this data into DB as below:

```
id  mgr_id  staff_id
1   3       5
2   4       4
3   4       5
```

When I am trying to loop through this array in php, I am getting an error "Array to string conversion". I used below code for looping:

```
$data = $_POST['pdata'];
foreach($data as $val){
    print_r($val);
}
```

The result of print_r is showing below result, it is showing only values but not keys:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 8
)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See what you get with `print_r($val)` in your loop.

Comment: We don’t see any JSON in your `$_POST` here, did you already decode it at this point? There’s no `pdata` in that array either, where does that come from?

Comment: None of the code you show is producing said error. What’s your *actual* database related code?

Comment: @deceze, I want to save the above array into mysql DB using php. I want to save that as mgr_id & staff_id

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['pdata'] as $mgr_id => $staff) foreach ($staff as $staff_id) echo "INSERT INTO ... ($mgr_id, $staff_id)"`…?! Just make that into a proper SQL query, including proper parameter escaping/binding.

Comment: @deceze, Thank you it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print because $val is array you cant use as echo to print array.

You have to use print_r($val);

```
$data = $_POST['pdata'];
foreach($data as $val){
    print_r($val);          
}
```

Question what is exactly want to do by using echo ?

Comment: Print_r($val); is showing below array
    Array
    (
    [0] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 8
)